How to bypass "Requires Apple silicon Mac" in Xcode
I am trying to build an app for Vision Pro and have spent a good amount of time preparing for it with what I have, an old MacBook 12 inch. Therefore, I needed to find a way to update it to Sonoma OS, and I used OpenCore Legacy Patcher to accomplish that.

Now, I’ve encountered another issue: in Xcode, it will not download the visionOS platform. This option is greyed out with the message "Requires Apple silicon Mac." Is there any way to bypass this and download it for Xcode so I can start selecting the Vision Pro device in my simulator? Additionally, some Vision Pro devices are running on visionOS 2.0, but I only see an option (which is greyed out) for visionOS 1.0. Is there something wrong with this?


You will need Xcode 15 for visionOS 2.0. You need an Apple Silicon Mac for visionOS development.

You cannot release apps for visionOS on Intel Macs, see this discussion, which is unfortunate and kind of unfair for Intel Mac users.
You can, however, try out visionOS on an Intel Mac with Xcode 15.0 beta and macOS Ventura, which is the latest and only version that supports visionOS Simulator on an Intel Mac. Because this Xcode has a beta runtime, one cannot release an app with it.

2 questions regarding your info: Can I downgrade to Xcode 15.0 beta and use with my Sonoma Os for this purpose or need to reinstall the OS as well? Can I use this Xcode 15.0 beta to build app (sideload) ipa file to my Vision Pro?

I recall it didn't work after I upgraded to Sonoma on my Intel machine. One suggested viable version combo was Xcode 15A5229m + Ventura. I didn't have a Vision Pro device by then, and now I'm using a M-chip to build, so I don't know the answer to the 2nd Q.

As long as it could download visionOS and build the code for that device in the simulator, I assume it will work for the real device?

Theoretically it should, yes, at least from the experience on iPhone and iPad. I assume it would work for VisionPro as well, though I can't verify that.

I followed your advice and installed Xcode 15A5229m along with Sonoma. I can download visionOS 1.0 in Xcode and access the code for it. However, I'm unable to connect my Vision Pro as a device in Xcode. I can pair it, but it doesn't show up afterward. Someone mentioned that if you've updated the VP to vOS 1.0.2 with the February 6, 2024 update, pairing with Xcode 15.2 won't work. You would need Xcode 15.3 beta 2. My VP is running visionOS 2.0. I tried downloading Xcode 15.3 beta 2, but the issue persists; I can pair it, but it still doesn't appear, and I've restarted both the PC and the VP.

Thanks for your update. Would you mind editing my reply to include your observation? It may help future readers decide whether they want to pursue this path or not. p.s. that sounds like a soft restriction Apple puts out with their OS update…

I tried to edit, but it says there are too many edits in the queue. I'm not sure what the issue is. I waited a day and tried again, but it's still the same.
